# Alinhamento de campos HTML

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Tenho um formulário [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/) para um `landing page`. 
 
Quero colocar os campos de data inicial e data final um ao lado do outro, sem quebrar meu responsivo.

```
<div class="col-lg-offset-3 col-lg-6 col-md-offset-2 col-md-8 col-sm-offset-2 
            col-sm-8 col-xs-offset-2 col-xs-8">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Período</label>
        <div class="form-inline">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div id="inicial">
                        <label>Data inicial</label>
                        <input type="date" class="form-control" 
                               placeholder="Período inicial">
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <label>Data final</label>
                        <input type="date" class="form-control" 
                               placeholder="Período final">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Elabore: "_sem quebrar meu responsivo_".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acho que seria isso que você queria, apenas acrescentei um `id='final'` na sua div do segundo campo e após, um CSS para formatação deles lado a lado.

---

[Fiddle de exemplo](https://jsfiddle.net/dxzu26fp/)

```css
#inicial {float: left; width: auto;}
#final {float: left; width: auto;}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="col-lg-offset-3 col-lg-6 col-md-offset-2 col-md-8 col-sm-offset-2 
            col-sm-8 col-xs-offset-2 col-xs-8">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Período</label>
        <div class="form-inline">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div id="inicial">
                        <label>Data inicial</label>
                        <input type="date" class="form-control" 
                               placeholder="Período inicial">
                    </div>
                    <div id="final">
                        <label>Data final</label>
                        <input type="date" class="form-control" 
                               placeholder="Período final">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Tente dessa maneira:

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
            <div class="form-group form-group-default input-group">
                <label>Data Inicial</label>
                <input type="date" class="form-control" placeholder="Período inicial"></i></span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
            <div class="form-group form-group-default input-group">
                <label>Data Final</label>
                <input type="date" class="form-control" placeholder="Período final">
            </div>
        </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Acho que se colocar uma formatação `CSS` pra ficar lado a lado, aí sua resposta fica correta, pois assim fica um abaixo do outro.

Comment: @MarcosHenzel Correto. Tens razão.